# Where do graduates in Chemistry from small PhD programs in the U.S go?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, chemistry

I am gathering information about the universities I intend to apply later this year and I've noticed that even in small graduate programs, most faculty members come from top universities such as Harvard, UC Berkeley etc. I was wondering, if those "small" programs are awarding degrees to many candidates every year, where do they go after the PhD is complete? In which field can these professionals find employability?

I'm sorry if this question is too obvious but as a foreign applicant, I don't know exactly how it works in the U.S.

Comment: industry research/engineering positions

Comment: Industry, or academic positions where no PhDs are granted (e.g. small non-selective liberal arts colleges.) For Chemistry specifically, let me recommend you read Chemjobber: http://chemjobber.blogspot.com/ who has sections on "industry vs academia" job search stats, etc....

Comment: Lots of small programs have very low rates of producing PhD's- a small program might only produce one new PhD per year.

Comment: You could ask the schools of your interest where their graduates are. Most should be happy to oblige, if only to show off.